# Retrieving the documents from the collection of Mongo db based on today's date

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mongo, spring-mongodb

I am newbie to mongodb, I have some issues while querying the database to retrieve the documents based on the current date.
While saving the document to database, I am setting the billingDate field by using

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
Date d = sdf.parse(billingDate);
```

So the Date field of my database is:

```
"billingDate" : ISODate("2017-01-02T00:00:00Z")
```

I tried to query as follows:

```
Query query=new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("billingDate").lte(new java.util.Date()));
```

By executing the above query, I am getting the previous bills as well but I need only for today(I don't want to consider the timestamp in it). Please help me to get the bills of current date only. Any suggestions would be appreciable.

Comment: What Jdk version do you use ?

Comment: Jdk version is 1.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this. This will get you the current date with time set to midnight in UTC.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(localDate, LocalTime.MIDNIGHT);
Instant instant = localDateTime.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
Date date = Date.from(instant);
```

Comment: Hi Sagar, thanks for your answer. your code worked partially for me, coz I am getting the bills for today and also the bills of future date as well :-( So how I should modify my code to get only for today without any timestamp and the future dates.

Comment: The answer I provided doesn't take timestamps in to consideration. So I'm not sure what you mean by  "only for today without any timestamp". Can you add some examples to the post and I can update my answer accordingly ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response Sagar :-) Yeah that is fine. But I am getting the bills of future dates as well, so please let me know how it can be avoided.

Comment: use the equality operator. something like `Criteria.where("billingDate").is(date)`. Is that what you are after ?

Comment: wowww :-) :-) Thanks a bunch buddy. U saved me. That is what I was looking for, loads of thanks to you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your criteria is wrong, you are using lte which means less than equal. Use eq

http://api.mongodb.com/java/3.0/?com/mongodb/client/model/Filters.html

Comment: I tried the same but eq is not supporting with the above query. :-(